# Confused about the tutorial on the "Rust  and WebAssembly " website

Tags: rust, webassembly

I tried the [Hello World Example](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html) about rust and webassembly here (on macbookpro 2018)

But got stuck at the last test step.

I changed **index.js** and **package.json** according to the tutorial

**index.js**

```
import * as wasm from "wasm-game-of-life";
wasm.greet();
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "wasm-game-of-life": "file:../pkg",
  "hello-wasm-pack": "^0.1.0",
  "webpack": "^4.29.3",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0"
}
```

I also tried to add a seperate part in **package.json** like below

```
"dependencies": {
  "wasm-game-of-life": "file:../pkg"
}
```

Sadly, they both didn't work.

The toolchains I used while going through the example

```
rustup 1.18.3
rustc 1.35.0
cargo 1.35.0
npm 6.9.0
node v10.15.3
```

The exact error message below:

```
(base) ➜  www git:(master) npm run start

> create-wasm-app@0.1.0 start /Users/updrew/workspace/rust playground/wasm-game-of-life/www
> webpack-dev-server

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/updrew/workspace/rust playground/wasm-game-of-life/www
✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 2c7b176d8a66be382dd2
Version: webpack 4.32.2
Time: 332ms
Built at: 05/28/2019 11:13:57 AM
         Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
0.bootstrap.js  672 bytes       0  [emitted]
  bootstrap.js    354 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
    index.html  175 bytes          [emitted]
Entrypoint main = bootstrap.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ./bootstrap.js 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./bootstrap.js] 279 bytes {main} [built]
[./index.js] 57 bytes {0} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/events/events.js] 13.3 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/html-entities/index.js] 231 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js] 127 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost 9.26 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {main} [built]
    + 12 hidden modules

ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'wasm-game-of-life' in '/Users/updrew/workspace/rust playground/wasm-game-of-life/www'
 @ ./index.js 1:0-42 2:0-10
 @ ./bootstrap.js
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Check the ../pkg directory and double check to ensure that 'wasm-game-of-life' exists there.  If it doesn't change the path in package.json to point to it.

Another issue could be you forgot to run npm install in the wasm-game-of-life/www subdirectory

Comment: Thanks for that. It turns out that I have to **npm install** twice, first before changing the files as the step told in the tutorial and then after changing them. It is kind of strange since it has been explicitly stated that **This command only needs to be run once** on the web.

Comment: That is odd but glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Had same issue (windows), didn't manage to solve it by just running install twice before run. Just like OP I attempted both with the entry in devDependencies and dependencies, but neither worked. *I did however solve it by having the entry in **both** at same time*. I ran install twice as well just to be sure, but from the output I have a feeling only once was needed. Will paste output below (out of characters).

Comment: ```npm install  
npm WARN The package wasm-game-of-life is included as both a dev and 
production dependency.  
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 
fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):  
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})  

added 1 package, removed 1 package and audited 9101 packages in 2.879s  
found 0 vulnerabilities  


npm install  
[same warnings]  

audited 9101 packages in 2.799s  
found 0 vulnerabilities```

Answer (score -1):

1. Change "devDependencies" to "dependencies"
2. Replace "hello-wasm-pack": "^0.1.0" with "wasm-game-of-life": "file:../pkg"

It will look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "wasm-game-of-life": "file:../pkg",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
  "webpack": "^4.16.3",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
}
```